# Download specific rows from database as csv file in struts

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans, struts

I need Java code for for downloading specific rows from database, in CSV format. I'm using the Netbeans IDE and Structs.

I used the following code in my action class:

```
else if (mode.equalsIgnoreCase("download"))
{
    if(null !=request.getParameter("batchid")){
        batch_id=request.getParameter("batchid");
    }
     UploadVO uploadvo= new UploadVO();          
        filetype = uploadform.getFiletype();
        filename = uploadform.getFilename(); 
    try{
        String sqls = "select ROW_NUMBER() over(order by id) as  row,trx_batch_id,account_id,"
                    + "(select name from [user] where id=tt.user_id) as Uploadedby,(SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),101) ) as date_of_transaction,"
                    + "amount,(select description from [_transaction_type] where type=tt.type) as type,note,reverse_transaction_id from"
                    + " [transaction] tt  "+ "where trx_batch_id= '" +batch_id+ "'" ;

            Statement stmts = con.createStatement();

            ResultSet rss = stmts.executeQuery(sqls);
            while (rss.next()) {

            byte[] ba;
            Blob b = rss.getBlob("content");
            ba = b.getBytes(1, (int) b.length());
            uploadvo.setDocfile(ba);
            }
    }
    catch(Exception e){

    }
   if (filetype.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("text/plain")) {
        response.setContentType("text/plain");
    } else if (filetype.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("application/ms-doc")) {
        response.setContentType("application/ms-doc");
    } else if (filetype.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("application/ms-excel")) {
        response.setContentType("application/ms-excel");
    } else if (filetype.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("pdf")) {
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    } else if (filetype.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("ppt")) {
        response.setContentType("application/ppt");
    } else if (filetype.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("application/vnd.ms-excel")) {
        response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
    } else if (filetype.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("image/jpeg")) {
        response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
    } else {
        response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
    }


    String disHeader = "Attachment; Filename= " + filename + "";
    System.out.println(disHeader);
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", disHeader);
    response.setHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");

    ServletOutputStream outs = response.getOutputStream();
    outs.write(uploadvo.getDocfile());
    outs.flush();
    outs.close();
    return mapping.findForward("success");

}
```

but I'm getting a null pointer exception.

Comment: Please include the stack trace for the `NullPointerException` - it will tell you the line number the error occurred on and will help people answer you question much more easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `fileType.trim()` without checking if it's null or not.

Things you're not asking for, but should be mentioned.

Apache Commons has a class StringUtils which is great for checking if strings are empty, 
so instead of writing

```
if (null !=request.getParameter("batchid"))
```

you'd write

```
if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(request.getParameter("batchid"))
```

Since you're probably interested in knowing if it contains something but spaces.

Also, your

```
else if (mode.equalsIgnoreCase("download"))
```

indicates that you're switching on `mode` (which I'm not sure if you've checked for `null` either). In struts 1.x, you can use `DispatchAction` in which you specify a paramter, eg mode, which will be the name of a method called, so in your example you'd implement a method

```
public ActionForward download(...) {
...
}
```

which would be called when `"download".equals(request.getParameter("mode")`.

Also note that writing `"download".equals(request.getParameter("mode")` rather than `request.getParameter("mode").equals("download")` saves you from a potential null-pointer